# How to Modify json File with dart

Tags: json, flutter, geojson

I'm creating a interactive map of my campus, the ideia is to replicate what I did on uMaps, [in this link](http:////umap.openstreetmap.fr/pt-br/map/mapa-interativo-furg_354207?scaleControl=false&miniMap=false&scrollWheelZoom=false&zoomControl=true&allowEdit=false&moreControl=true&searchControl=null&tilelayersControl=null&embedControl=null&datalayersControl=true&onLoadPanel=undefined&captionBar=false). The geojson was downloaded and I'm using the coordinates that came with it.

The issue is my coordinates in the json, originally were a GeoJson, are sorted wrongly, my long came first then lat, thus when parse Google Maps can't read properly.
Json:

[image]

Anyone knows how to modify json files in Flutter?

Any help, advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Even if this is a one-off thing on a file, you might invest an afternoon learning about "jq", which can do some amazing manipulation of JSON files.  If this JSON was generated incorrectly, you can fix that and rerun your program.

Comment: And if you had followed the recommendation to share editable text instead of a screenshot, I would have gladly spent the 5 minutes coming up with the right jq line.  Note that for the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can try overwriting like this

```
  String jsonData = '{"name":"user name"}';
  await File('yourFileName').writeAsString(jsonData);
```